# Programmatically surrounding a Python input in quotes

Tags: python, string, ip

Using the netaddr Python library tutorial (https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html) I am creating a program that allows a user to input an IP address that gets added to a list, the only problem being it needs to be converted to an IP object first.

```
ip = input('Enter a valid IP Address/Subnet: ')
ip_list = IPNetwork(ip)
print('You have selected: ', ip_list)
```

When I run the program and enter:

> 192.168.1.1

I get

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\IPAddress.py", line 4, in <module>
>     ip = input('Enter a valid IP Address/Subnet: ')
>   File "<string>", line 1
>     192.168.1.1
>         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

However when i surround the IP in quotes it seems to work

> '192.168.1.1'

I get my desired result

> ('You have selected: ', IPNetwork('192.168.1.1/32'))

My question is how can I allow the user to enter an IP address without having to surround it in quotes themselves i.e. it will be done programatically

Comment: would taking the input as a string, append a single quotes to the back and front and then putting it into IPNetwork work?

Comment: Why not use raw_input? It doesn't have this error.

Comment: You're using Python 3 style python. Why not just use Python 3?  (In Python 3 `print` is a function and `input` returns a string — the equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're using Python 2.  Use `raw_input` instead of `input` and it will work.  With `input`, if you enter a number you will get a number type (`int` for integer, `float` for floating point, etc).  The IP address confuses things as it doesn't understand why more than one decimal point exists.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer runs down

Comment: @CMac: Or just use Python 3. It appears that's what your reference or tutorial is using.